# Logarithmic curve with spiralling cross-section

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm trying to make a logarithmic curve with a rotating cross-section.

I have created a curve object following the instructions at
[How to create this kind of spiral tube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19108/how-to-create-this-kind-of-spiral-tube), giving me the curve shown below, which has an elliptical cross-section that increases in size along the length of the curve.

However, as well as the size of the ellipse increasing along the curve, I would like it to twist, giving a 'corkscrewing' final result that will superficially resemble *fusilli* pasta.

It seems like this should be a simple thing to do, but I can't see a way to do it.  Can anybody help?

[image: Un-corkscrewing curve]
<sub>(source: [dur.ac.uk](https://community.dur.ac.uk/martin.smith/img/curve.png))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the *tilt* property of the curve's control points?

If you select one or more curve vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> you enter tilt editing mode where you can control the twisting effect of the curve.

Depending on how your curve was built you can control this for one or more vertex at a time.

If you need to make a smooth gradient across a multitude of points you can use *Proportional editing* <kbd>O</kbd> key to affect adjacent vertex. Use <kbd>Mouse wheel</kbd>  to adjust the affected radius.

[image: Curve Tilt]

Comment: Brilliant – that's just the job.  Thank you.