# Smooth selection along a curve

Tags: bezier-curves, selection-tools

I would like to know how I can make a smooth selection along a curve (like proportional editing object mode). 
If i use proportional editing object mode with a spiral and a large radius of smoothness the tool will grab the turn under the one selected which i don't want.
I want to grab one end of my spiral and deform it along it own curve.
... hope I'm clear enough :D

Many thx

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your problem and what you want to do.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: In the proportional editing choose "Connected".

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section/56398#56398

Comment: Maybe a better way of deforming a spiral along a curve, though, is to use a Curve modifier?

Comment: Connected do exactly what I was looking for! Thx!