# Piping cream through a piping tip

Tags: collision, soft-body

I would like to simulate piping of a cream through a piping tip. I modeled the piping tip as you can see.  I added a soft body to the cylinder, and then I set the piping to collision.  But for some reason it doesn't go through instead it stops midway. I would like to render an image of the cream after deformation.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to create such an effect?

Comment: Ussually Fluid sim is used for that, like here I used FlipFluid addon https://vimeo.com/305101552 , but current Mantaflow solver could work as well? Just create star object and use it as Flow object.

Comment: you could fake it by passing a cylinder through a lattice

Comment: I would recommend the use of fluid simulation with a increased amount of viscosity

Comment: @vklidu Can you post a link to a tutorial.

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Seems like the solution I'm looking for, but I'm not that advanced in fluid simulation. Can you recommend a tutorial to follow.

Comment: This question (and answers) deserve upvotes ... because yummy

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I run a pastry shop, Come visit, I'll treat you to some :) https://goo.gl/maps/v5Wqn5m55MdcyqKi8 . and of course everyone tried to help me out.

Answer (score 28):

### Flip Fluid addon [$]

- create **star** (you can use *Extra Objects* addon) and animate movement
- under *Physics Properties* enable *Flip Fluid* > type **Inflow**
- add *Cube* object and scale it to *Domain* dimension
- under *Physics Properties* enable *Flip Fluid* type **Domain**
- under *FLIP Fluid World* enable **Viscosity**
- *Bake*

[image]
[image]
Credits for [Cup-Cake model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1xxckEa_FA) goes to MrSorbias.

[image]

### Mantaflow

in general same system (domain / inflow). I just wasnt able to setup enough viscosity without strange behaviour of particles. This area doesn't seems to be covered in Mantaflow solver. You can find a parameters in *Physics Properties* editor under *Diffusion*, but from what I saw on net, most thick liquid is still too far from cream with ability to keep a form.

For more details [check this intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcsxPAbGsKM)

Comment: This is a very useful answer

Comment: Perfect answer ... exactly what I recommended.Though I wasn't that perfect in fluid simulation

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include a detailed explanation of a mantaflow system to do the simulation in the first gif?

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Like I wrote in the description, I wasn't successful with internal solver ... Still too meltish ... But here someone seems to did it https://youtu.be/ecclMut3pis see setup at the end of video.

Answer (score 11):

To expand on my comment, and if you only need the moment the cream passes through the tip, an easy way to fake it would be to pass a cylinder through a lattice.

[image: steps]

Start with a cylinder with a few edge loops and a subdivision modifier. Add a Lattice with an uneven number of `U` and `V` divisions and 3 `W` division. Scale the middle `W` to zero, then make the bottom of the lattice into a star shape matching the shape of you tip.
Add the lattice modifier to the cylinder and now, moving it along the Z axis will deform it as if it'd been through the tip.

[image: anim]

Now, this is obviously just a quick and simple way to fake it, and you might need to use more complicated softbody or fluids simulations if you want more realism. But I thought it was worth pointing out this technique.

Comment: Nice technique, I've tried that. The issue is I don't know the shape of the cylinder after deformation and I was hoping to find a way to make blender compute that shape based on the piping tip shape.

Answer (score 11):

Being a curve addict here is a solution using bezier objects for this.

[image: Demo]

Create three sets of bezier curves:

1. Section shapes for varying cylinder tips
2. Piped cream objects themselves
3. Taper shape(s)

Create varying bezier curve shapes for the foreseeable piping bag tips you'll be using.
These were created from mesh circles with different number of segments and converted to bezier curves after the fact.

[image: Sections]

Create a [taper object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564). This curve will be used to control the shape/width of the piped cream along its length. Position along the Y axis of the mid vertex will set the width of the puff at its widest point.

[image: Taper Object]

Create a bezier curve object for the piped cream itself. Optionally give it a twist with the [*Tilt*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396) function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in *Edit Mode*). Adjust its shape length and twist as desired.

[image]

Set the *Taper Object* to the taper curve created above and set the *Bevel Object* to one of the desired sections.

Turn on the option *Map Taper* so the bevel isn't clipped but instead "slides" along its length.

[image: Map Taper]

Now animate the *End* Bevel property to simulate the squirting action.

[image]

For added dynamism you can create and animate the influence of additional shape-keys in both the taper and main curves, to simulate gravity squashing and the elasticity of the cream.