# How would you make a clay coil pot in blender?

Tags: animation, texturing, sculpting

I can find lots of examples of cable coils and spring coils, and lots of examples of how to make clay textures, but how would you go about animating the coils of a clay coil pot?

This kind of thing:

[image]

Comment: Hello, what is the animation you're talking about?

Comment: I want to animate the act of the clay being laid down onto the pot, so I guess some kind of phycis/particle type arrangement, but I'm not sure how to even begin to search for it, as it isn't really a fluid dynamic - more a like a Mr Whippy ice cream is that makes sense?

Comment: This noodle tutorial seems to get close: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lg7jxAMs60Q&ab_channel=BlenderHD

Comment: do you mean this kind of effect? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsScC.gif

Comment: No, more like plasticene or toothpaste (clay) being squeezed out of a tube in a circular shape to build up the sides of a pot

Comment: So maybe this? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/196776/19156

Comment: That's very close, but when I change the path to overlap itself, the toothpaste won't lie on top of itself... I need to be able to build upwards with my curves...