# Extrude a bevel on a spiral

Tags: error, extrude, origin

Per request I'm sharing the blender file here (it's not much to look at, but I've included 3 examples of "Bad Icing")

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KeWtvCJwlbIDJarljetxRaj0o964EA07?usp=sharing

I've seen so many examples of spirals, but none of them seem to hit my exact need.

I'm attempting to build some icing for a cupcake I'm designing.  I'm also SUPER new to Blender, this is literally Hello World v2.0 (I like a billion others made the donut first).

Here is a summary of what I tried. In frame one you can see that the curve "Seems fine".

[image: Summary of my issue]

I've gotten "somewhat" closer using a spherical path but still not all I had hoped for.  Most of the archimedean don't work as I can't get their X scale down, or there are gaps between the icing. I also tried building an array of my extrude shape, but I couldn't get it to do a "Screw" shape.  Any suggestions, recommendations or tutorials you might recommend are welcome!  At this point I'm not even worried about trying to twist my extruded object to get the perfect match.

I appreciate you taking the time to read through this!
Paul

Comment: try changing the orientation of the circle in edit mode. also make sure the object origin is correct. try sharing your blend file for better help https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Shantanu added the file, thanks for the tip!  I'm going to mess with orientations and object origins now.
That is REALLY a cool extrusion, it's not *quite* the shape I'm going for but I'm going to check it out for sure

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187019/piping-cream-through-a-piping-tip/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Object origin is not at the center of the Object.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html

> Each object has an origin point. The location of this point determines where the object is located in 3D space. When an object is selected, a small circle appears, denoting the origin point. The location of the origin point is important when translating, rotating or scaling an object. See [Pivot Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html) for more.

When using the object as bevel, the origin of the object is moved along the curve to obtain the beveled curve. Since your origin is off, the result is unexpected.

Fix:

- Select the object > right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry.

  [image: Set object origin]
- [image: Result]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much!  Looking forward to getting this all fixed up.  Instantly fixed my issue.