# How to build a 3D spiral (not a helix)?

Tags: geometry

I've been looking for ways to build a 3D spiral in Blender, but every time I search for it, I find techniques for building a helix.  I'm not looking for a helix; I'm looking for a 2D spiral, extruded up into the 3rd dimension.

Does anyone have any pointers for creating one?

Comment: Could you illustrate what you want to achieve with some reference images?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Something along the lines of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_bold_spiral.svg

Comment: [You should add that image to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for this:

https://youtu.be/-ckk8GVGv6o

Basically you use the shrinkwrap and the screw modifier to do this.

1. build a circle
2. use modifier screw and apply it
3. build a cone and scale and move it as you need it in the screwed circle
4. now use modifier shrinkwrap with object cone on your circle
5. scale z value to 0 so that you have "flat" screw

Comment: Hi. Please try to elaborate a bit more in your answer. Link only answer are not well accepted in BSE.

Comment: ok, i tried. but i really think an explanation video helps much more that 1000 words, because you can "live" see how to get there. but thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: This is not the point: the answer will mean nothing if the video become unavailable in the future.