# How can I create this circular but non symmetric shape (in 3D)?

Tags: modeling

How can I create the following shape (in 3D, similar to a torus). I only want one of the "circle shapes" (i.e not the two you see overlapping). Any ideas how one might create this?

[image]

Similar to this maybe (i.e. the difference in thinkness between on side of the ring and the other side not quite as extreme as above). I am talking about the **bottom right object of the objects in the image** below. Also maybe without the sharp line on top. **Clarification:** I need the bottom right object of the below image (or something similar to it with the first image above as inspiration), not the other open objects seen below as well.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to guess what it would give in 3D, what do you mean when you say "similar to a torus"?

Comment: Check the bottom right of the second image I have added. This is how it could look like in 3D. Something similar to this. How would one go about creating this?

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @Paul actually I didn't post any answer because I'm still not sure what you want  ;)

Comment: @moonboots Fair point. I will try a more clear question tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

A quick and dirty way is with a bezier curve.

Add a bezier curve circle, add some bevel thickness.

Enter *Edit Mode*, and turn on *Proportional Edit*. [Adjust the influence radius](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale) so it reaches only three of the four curve vertex.

Select only one of the four vertex, then adjust its *Radius* property to zero using *Proportional Edit* with <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

Beware that this wont ensure both the inner and outer outline are exactly perfectly circular as illustrated in your image, but it is an approximation

Optionally adjust the number of *Bevel Segments* to a lower number if you want a hard edge.

You may also want to look into the [Tilt property of curves for a twisting effect](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section).

Comment: Farrajota Thanks. Is its possible to make it sig. thicker on the one side like the image? Also is it possible to model in more detail like the (middle) sharper ridge you see in the object (the second picture bottom right).

Comment: Bottom right picture is not possible with this technique, as far as I can tell from the picture. All other are possible using an open curve instead of a closed circle. You can use a custom section object with a triangular shape as *Bevel Object* and use the same *Proportional Edit* workflow to control scale along the path

Comment: You can also play with the tilt property. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56396/logarithmic-curve-with-spiralling-cross-section

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Comment asked for the closed shape; so I'll outline a way to do the symmetric version of it first.  See the Open Shape for more details on how to do each step.

### Closed shape with symmetry

- Create a mesh circle with a reasonable number of vertices.
- Remove all of the vertices from one side.
- Convert it to a curve.
- Create a mesh circle with three vertices.
- Edit it to the profile shape you want.
- Create a Bezier Curve.  Edit it to be the profile shape.
- Set the taper and bevel objects of the half circle curve to the profile and triangle.
- Add a mirror modifier.

Here's an example:

### [image: Closed symmetric ring]
Open shape

I would do this by relying on a curve's bevel and taper properties.  Here is one of the open circle designs done this way:

- Create a mesh circle with a reasonable number of vertices. For the example I've chosen the default 32.
- In *Edit* mode delete a few adjacent vertices to create the gap. For the example I've chosen just one:
  [image: Mesh circle with missing vertices]
- In *Object* mode convert it to a curve using Object → Convert → Curve menu entry.
- In *Object* mode add another mesh circle but give it 3 vertices to create a triangle.
- Edit the triangle to get the narrow profile you want.  This will become the shape of your 3D object.  Scale it down and apply scale.
  [image]
- In *Object* mode convert it to a curve.
- Select your first curve and go to object data properties.
- Open the Bevel panel if it's not open and select "Object".
- Set the object to your triangle shaped curve.  I called mine "triangle".
  [image: Setting the Bevel object]
- In *Object* mode add a Bezier curve.
- Go back to the original curve, and open the Geometry panel if it's not open.
- Set the "Taper Object" to your new Bezier Curve.
- Edit the new Bezier Curve to get the taper you want.  Here's one that goes smoothly from one end to the other, leaving a small opening at the tip. (I used automatic vectors to get the straight line.
  [image: Bezier curve for smooth taper]

Here's my hurried version.  With a bit of editing on the triangle and the Bezier taper you can reproduce any of the shape except the closed one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the closed shape (i,e. bottom right object of the second image) is the one I need. Not the open ones. Any idea how to create that? Or an object similar to the first image (however only one circle not two overlapping, see original post) but in 3D?

Comment: The closed shape is easier than the open shape if you want a symmetric object; but the bottom right image is not symmetric.  I'll ad the symmetric version to my answer.

Comment: If you show me how to do the bottom right object, that would be great.

Comment: To get the bottom ring without the sharp edge, proportional edit a torus.

Comment: Can you demonstrate with the sharp ridge and without? I would be interested in how to do the bottom right object. I would also be interested in the bottom right shape (or first photo as inspiration), i.e. without the sharper ridge. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Mobius solidified]

For that last shape you need a circle curve that is not cyclic, so it's final point needs to be in the same position as the starting point.

[image: not cyclic circle curve]

Here I moved the end point to show that it's not cyclic:

[image: not cyclic circle end point]

Then you tilt the curve points from start to end, starting with a tilt of 0 and ending with a tilt of 180.

[image: curve points tilt]

After that, you adjust the radius of the points.

Now the curve bevel:

[image: Curve Bevel options]

If the curve will have smooth shading, add a weld modifier so the curve's start and end connect.

Comment: I'm working on a better method to give something that is more circular.

Comment: yes that would be good. In the object I posted center and outside is much more circular.